# How do I insert headers in Internet Explorer?

Tags: developer-tools, ie-developer-tools

How do I insert headers names and values such as access tokens and its values in IE?.Just like this one on the left with Edge. It has a storage tab and session tab on the left to which I could put the necessary headers to override the login and OTP. This is also available in Chrome

[image: Inserting Header in Edge]
It's just that I want to override our apps OTP function and login by inserting the values needed for it to skip the OTP and login. It just so happen that I need to test our apps compatibility with IE , but then I'm stuck on our very own login to which I could not do and bypass the security. Where do I find or insert the tokens needed to. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Got a help from a colleague.

Turns out. In the console, you should type

sessionStorage.setItem("accessToken","valueOfToken");

then press enter to insert the header.

[image: Header Input]

After entering the value, when you type sessionStorage and press enter. You'd then finally be able to see the header that's going to be sent by IE. In my case its the accessToken header and its value.